# root_url returns empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise

So I'm trying to put a link in an email using link_to. The application that sends the email is installed in development and staging envs on two separate servers but they are configured the exact same way for now. For some reason, this line :

```
<p><%= link_to t('.action'), "#{root_url}#!/?reset_password_token=#{@token}" %></p>
```

works well and displays a link to www.mywebsite.com/... in dev env, but it won't in staging env, displaying a link to localhost:5000/... instead.
config.action_mailer.default_url_options is well configured in my conf files and application_controller.
I also checked the log and it looks like {root_url} returns an empty string in staging env, but not in dev.
I've been trying to understand for hours now but I just don't get it.

Thank you in advance for your help !

**Edit** : This is how I configured default_url_options

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
:host => Rails.application.secrets.default_host, 
:protocol => Rails.application.secrets.default_protocol }
```

And this what DEFAULT_HOST and DEFAULT_PROTCOL look like in my application.yml :

```
DEFAULT_HOST: mywebsite.com
DEFAULT_PROTOCOL: http
```

And I also got this in my application_controller.rb :

```
def default_url_options 
{ 
:host => Rails.application.secrets.default_host, 
protocol: Rails.application.secrets.default_protocol 
}
end
```

**Edit 2** : I still didn't manage to find a solution for my problem. The application I use uses sidekiq but none of sidekiq configs seems to override the default_url_options. If anyone has an idea..
Also, if I type "Rails.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]" in rails console, I do get "=> "mywebsite.com".

Comment: Can you show how you have configured `default_url_options`?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the issue. I had to restart sidekiq so the changes in the code could be taken into account. Now the emails won't send but this is another issue lol

Answer (score 0):

Try #{request.domain}, it also works, and make sure your IDE is detecting it as variable, not string

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer but it didn't work. I got an error message "undefined method `domain`"..